# Is there a way to convert Dockerfile to an EC2 instance (for example)?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile

Is there a way to convert Dockerfile to an EC2 instance (for example)?
I.e., a script to interpret the Dockerfile script and install all the correct versions of dependencies and any other deployment operations on a bare metal ec2 instance.

I do not mean to run the docker images inside Docker but to deploy it directly on the instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can do this with the help of tools, but you can do this with the help of Dockerfile itself.

First, choose the OS for your EC2 launch which used in the Dockerfile that you can find in the start of Dockerfile, suppose `FROM ubuntu`, so choose `ubuntu` for your EC2 machine rest of the command will be same for as you perform in the Dockerfile.

But again we also need behaviour like Docker means to say that we just want to create it *once and run on different EC2 machine* on a different region, so for this you need to launch the instance and prepare one instance and test it accordingly then create [AWS AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) from that EC2 instance, now you can treat this AWS AMI like Docker image.

**Amazon Machine Image (AMI)**

> An Amazon Machine Image (AMI) provides the information required to
> launch an instance. You must specify an AMI when you launch an
> instance. **You can launch multiple instances from a single AMI when you
> need multiple instances with the same configuration.** You can use
> different AMIs to launch instances when you need instances with
> different configurations

[creating-an-ami](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html#creating-an-ami)

Or the second option is to put the complete script in the [user-data section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), you can consider this entrypoint of the Docker where we want to prepare thing during run time.